# jOOQ JSON formatting as array of objects

Tags: json, jooq

I have the following (simplified) jOOQ query:

```kotlin
val result = context.select(
  jsonObject(
    key("id").value(ITEM.ID),
    key("title").value(ITEM.NAAM),
    key("resources").value(
      jsonArrayAgg(ITEM_INHOUD.RESOURCE_ID).absentOnNull()
    )
  )
).from(ITEM).fetch()
```

Now the output that I want is:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "0da04cc5-f70c-4fb3-b5c7-dc645d342631",
        "title": "Title1",
        "resources": [
            "8b0f6d5c-67fc-47ca-be77-d1735e7721ce",
            "ea0316db-1cfd-46d7-8260-5c1a4e65a0cd"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "0f7e67e6-5187-47e2-9f1d-dab08feba38b",
        "title": "Title2"
    }
]
```

`result.formtJSON()` gives the following output:

```json
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "json_object",
            "type": "JSON"
        }
    ],
    "records": [
        [
            {
                "id": "0da04cc5-f70c-4fb3-b5c7-dc645d342631",
                "title": "Title 1"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Disabling the headers with `result.formatJSON(JSONFormat.DEFAULT_FOR_RECORDS)` will get me:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "id": "0da04cc5-f70c-4fb3-b5c7-dc645d342631",
            "title": "Title1",
            "resources": [
                "8b0f6d5c-67fc-47ca-be77-d1735e7721ce",
                "ea0316db-1cfd-46d7-8260-5c1a4e65a0cd"
            ]
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id": "0f7e67e6-5187-47e2-9f1d-dab08feba38b",
            "title": "Title2"
        }
    ]
]
```

where I don't want the extra array.

Further customizing the JSONformatter with `result.formatJSON(JSONFormat().header(false).recordFormat(JSONFormat.RecordFormat.OBJECT))` I get:

```json
[
    {
        "json_object": {
            "id": "0da04cc5-f70c-4fb3-b5c7-dc645d342631",
            "title": "Title1",
            "resources": [
                "8b0f6d5c-67fc-47ca-be77-d1735e7721ce",
                "ea0316db-1cfd-46d7-8260-5c1a4e65a0cd"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "json_object": {
            "id": "0f7e67e6-5187-47e2-9f1d-dab08feba38b",
            "title": "Title2"
        }
    }
]
```

where I don't want the object wrapped in `json_object`.

Is there a way to get the output I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Doing it with `Result.formatJSON()`

This is clearly a flaw in the jOOQ 3.14.0 implementation of `Result.formatJSON()`. In the special case where there is only one column, and that column is of type `JSON` or `JSONB`, the column name may not really matter, and thus its contents should be flattened into the object describing the row. I've created a feature request for this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10953. It will be available in jOOQ 3.15.0 and 3.14.4. You will be able to do this:

```java
result.formatJSON(JSONFormat().header(false).wrapSingleColumnRecords(false));
```

The `RecordFormat` is irrelevant here. This works the same way for `RecordFormat.ARRAY` and `RecordFormat.OBJECT`

#### Doing it directly with SQL

Of course, you can always work around this by moving all the logic into SQL. You probably simplified your query by omitting a `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. I'm assuming this is equivalent to what you want:

```java
JSON result = context.select(
  jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
    key("id").value(ITEM.ID),
    key("title").value(ITEM.NAAM),
    key("resources").value(
      select(jsonArrayAgg(ITEM_INHOUD.RESOURCE_ID).absentOnNull())
      .from(ITEM_INHOUD)
      .where(ITEM_INHOUD.ITEM_ID.eq(ITEM.ID))
    )
  ))
).from(ITEM).fetchSingle().value1()
```

Note that `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` aggregates empty sets into `NULL`, not into an empty `[]`. [If that's a problem, use `COALESCE()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67932476/521799)